# Linux Bridge - multiple VLANs into default vlan

Tags: kvm-virtualization, vlan, bridge

I have a CentOS 6 Box (Kernel 2.6.32-642.6.1.el6.x86_64) where 2 KVM instances are running.

I am getting two VLANs from the datacenter. Unfortunately, they wont combine both VLANs to one VLAN. I need to use both VLANs at the same time on the same KVM guests.

The default VLAN is untagged and the second vlan is tagged on id 471.

Currently, i make it this way:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.0cc47a7fed0a       no              eth1
                                                        kvm1100.0
br1             8000.0cc47a7fed0a       no              eth1.471
                                                        kvm1101.0
```

That is working as expected. I can use the untagged VLAN on KVM instance 1100 and VLAN 471 on KVM instance 1101.

Now i want that KVM 1101 can use IP addresses from the untagged VLAN and from VLAN 471.

So I have added eth1.471 to br0 and then added kvm1101.0 to br0 too.

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.0cc47a7fed0a       no              eth1
                                                        eth1.471
                                                        kvm1100.0
                                                        kvm1101.0
```

That is working and I can access both VLANs on both instances. It works as I would like it.

But when eth1.471 gets added to br0 I see packet loss on the whole network. Not only on this server, it affects everything. When I remove eth.471 from br0 the packet loss stops.

It seems that this is not the correct way. I have tried various things but I always end up with the same result.

What am I missing? As mentioned, the datacenter is not willing to combine both VLANs to one.

It is not an option to pass the VLANs to the KVM instance and configure the VLAN + IP addresses there. The KVM instance should be able to use both vlans without additional configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bridge eth1 with eth1.174 you actually create a topology loop in the datacenter network on your interface, hence the packet loss and other woes.

The possible solution to your problem is introduction of a second interface to kvm1101 and add **that** KVM interface to br0, keeping br0 and br1 as separate bridges bound to their respective VLANs on the physical adapter.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a way to prevent the loop and keeping eth1.471 on br0 (ebtables or something?)? The problem is that i would need to change additional internal configurations to support a second bridge and i would like to keep the system behind as it is and give the instance only one interface.

Comment: I belive not, you cannot just bridge an interface onto itself. You need either something like a virtual switch or a second interface..

Comment: I have a Juniper EX4200 where all traffic passes. On the Juniper i have configurated the VLANs and there i assign the VLAN to the port. As far as i know the Juniper EX couldnt help with that case, right?

Comment: It depends on the use-case. Why do you need a separate VLAN in the first place, if you don't want to terminate it separately on the server side?

Comment: I dont need a seperate VLAN. I am getting 2 kinds of traffic from the datacenter. And the datacenter only gives it in seperate vlans. They cant merge it into one (or dont want to)

Comment: So, you have datacenter router/switch <---> EX4200 <----> server in question, right? And the datacenter feeds you these VLANs on a trunk and you then feed it as a trunk to the server, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly this is it.

Comment: If you don't need any specific L2 features available on KVM guests, you can terminate L2 on EX4200 and route L3 from there over a single L2 connection via native VLAN. Otherwise you'd still need to use two subinterfaces on a host and bridge them separately.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use two different IP addresses in different IP subnets in your VM, you need two different interfaces in your VM. There simply is no other way, because that is how IP works. The rule is that you cannot have two different IP subnets configured in the same L2 broadcast domain. This is also the reason why the datacenter refuses to combine them into one.

So, you need to have two virtual network adapters (`kvm1100.0` and `kvm1101.0`) assigned to your VM.

However, if your VM needs to listen to some specific ports on an IP address in your tagged VLAN, you can use NAT:

Host OS has configured an address in your tagged vlan (`br1` or `eth1.471`, bridge isn't actually needed here). Then, the host OS has port forwarding configured so that any incoming connection to the `eth1.471` interface IP address port X is forwarded to the guest VM IP address in `eth1` network.

You can also use NAT for outgoing traffic from the guest VM if you want some destinations to use the `eth1.471` as the outgoing interface.

Comment: I understand that. I am not planing to mix the IP addresses from the both VLANs on the KVM instances on the same network interface. The plan is that there is no additional config on our backend system necessary (here: switch instance to br1). I should be able to assign the kvm instance an IP from VLAN 1 and if i want i can change it to an IP from VLAN 2 without touching the KVM config because the instance is always on br0. Sadly, NAT is not an option for it.

Comment: The thing is that you cannot have two different IP subnetworks on a same L2 interface / broadcast domain. It doesn't matter if the IP addresses override each other or not. That is against the fundamentals of IP.